# Сброс id у выборных строк SQL

Tags: sql

В общем, есть таблица "вопрос" (id, cid - категория, vok - правильный ответ от 1 до 4), к нему таблица "ответ" (id, pid, title), к каждому вопросу есть 4 ответа.
Когда мы делаем выборку этих 4 ответов, они имеют id как в таблице. Как сделать, чтобы они имели id от 1 до 4? Чтобы можно было сверить значение radio с значение vok.

Ну или просто расскажите принципы построения QUIZ со случайной выборкой вопросов из категории и случайным разбросом ответов. И подробно, как сверить select с правильным ответом.

Comment: А почему бы не хранить в vok id из таблицы "ответ"?

Comment: Просто добавление из админки нового вопроса так устроено, что мы заранее не знаем id будущего ответа. Или знаем?

Comment: Ну либо у вас при добавлении вопроса неизвестно об ответе вообще ничего(а номер-то вы знаете, например), либо вы можете получить id в том же запросе, где title.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что столбец vok (типа да/нет) должен быть не в таблице "вопрос", а в таблице "ответ". Это, помимо прочего, позволит иметь вопросы с несколькими правильными ответами.

Answer (score 1):

```
/* таблицы которые хранят общую информацию о вопросах */
// таблица где хранятся доступные вопросы
create table question_def (question_id, question_title, is_multy_answer_allowed);
// ^^ здесь последнее поле устанавливает допускает ли вопрос множественные ответы

// таблица где хранятся данные о допустимых ответах
create table answer_def (answer_id, answer_category_id);
create table answer_value_def (id, answer_order, is_answer, value);  
// ^^ здесь order отвечает за порядок отображения и является частью PK вместе с id
// и имеет значение 1-4 для ваших radio
// is_answer поле определяет правильный это ответ или нет (напр 4 записи и только у одной стоит 1, она и есть правильным ответом на этот вопрос)

/* таблицы которые хранят результаты */
// таблица где хранятся данные об ответах на вопросы 
create table question (question_id, ...);
create answer (answer_id, question_id, player_id, ...);
create answer_value (answer_id, question_id, order_id, valu
```

e);

p.s. если у вас всегда будет только 4 опции то стоит заменить таблицы `*_value` на 4 поля в таблицах `question_def, answer_def` (в других таблицах сделать аналогично)